# Image inpainting / cvRectangle() 

Tags: c, image-processing, opencv

I am doing an image inpainting project. I got the area which I have to inpaint throught user selection(square) which will be a mask image which will be inpaint. Now i am using this code

```
cvRectangle(add_img,cvPoint(x,y),cvPoint(x1, y1),CV_RGB(255, 225, 225),CV_FILLED, 8,0);
```

to create the mask image. But when I am trying to access those pixels, I am not getting value `(255,255,255)` which would be white.

So my question is, when I add a `cvRectangle` on `add_img`, will it change the pixel value on `add_image` and make it `(255,255,255)` in the given area, or it will just add white squares over the image and underneath the square, with the original value remaining the same?

I don't want to use a `for` loop to set the RGB values to `(255,255,255)`. Is there another way to do it?

Comment: Please define "inpaint" for me.... I have never heard that term.

Comment: [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inpainting)  this will give you a simple idea about it. The are which we want to remove from image is selected by user and i am making it white so i can regenerate the missing block from near by pixel. i hope this is helpful.

Comment: As a stackoverflow user, it's good practice to select the answers that solved your questions (when there is one). I reviewed some of your previous questions and at least one of them you got what you asked. To select an answer as the official problem solver, click on the checkbox near it.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating the `cvRectangle` with one color (which is not white), and expecting it to be white:

```
// can you spot the difference between these 2 calls?
CV_RGB(255, 225, 225) 
CV_RGB(255, 255, 255)
```

Comment: You can improve the question, but you must not change it. If you have other questions then ask them in new threads, ok?